How to make async function to sync in NodeJS 22 without Fibers?
How to make async TOP-level function to sync in NodeJS 22 without Fibers?
console.log("aaa");
const asyncFn = new Promise((resolve) => {setTimeout(() => {reject("bbb")}, 100)});
console.log(asyncFn()); // This call of async function I need to make sync (in top-level, not wrapped to another async function with await)
console.log("ccc")

Is it possible to make async function sync in nodeJS 22 (without Fibers)?
Example2:
I added next exmaple, where function(...args) cannot be async, but some methods inside function are async (which I need to run synchronously)
methods.forEach(method => {
  const _orig = proto[method];
  proto[method] = function(...args) {
    if (directEnv.get()) return _orig.apply(this, args);
    // give the hooks a private context so that they can modify this.args without putting this.args onto the prototype
    const context = {args};
    const userId = getUserId();
    global.hookLogging && typeof args[0]!='string' && console.log('hook', '\n\n');

    // if the method is update or remove, automatically apply the find hooks to limit the update/remove to the user's group
    if ((method=='update' || method=='updateAsync' || method=='remove') && this._groupingBefore_find) {
      global.hookLogging && typeof args[0]!='string' && console.log('hook', 'b4i', this._name+"."+method, JSON.stringify(args[0]), JSON.stringify(args[1]));
      // don't send args[1] for update or remove.
      // need to send empty object instead to prevent args[1] being modified

// ========= THIS I NEED TO RUN SYNCHRONOUSLY
      this._groupingBefore_find.call(context, userId, args[0], {});


      global.hookLogging && typeof args[0]!='string' && console.log('hook', 'afi', this._name+"."+method, JSON.stringify(args[0]), JSON.stringify(args[1]));
    }

    // run the hook
    if (this['_groupingBefore_'+method]) {
      global.hookLogging && typeof args[0]!='string' && console.log('hook', 'b4', this._name+"."+method, JSON.stringify(args[0]), JSON.stringify(args[1]));

// ========= THIS I NEED TO RUN SYNCHRONOUSLY
      this['_groupingBefore_'+method].call(context, userId, args[0], args[1], args[2]);

      global.hookLogging && typeof args[0]!='string' && console.log('hook', 'af', this._name+"."+method, JSON.stringify(args[0]), JSON.stringify(args[1]));
    }

    // run the original method
    return _orig.apply(this, args);
  }
});


As far as I know: no. Why do you need to do this?

@AKX it's harder to explain, but In global scope, I'm creating a Mongo collection and after that (each collection), I need immediatelly call async method, which I need to make it sync (call it before use that collection).

Is top-level await not an option?

@AKX probably yes, but the problem is more deeper. I edited question, try to check Example2, where function cannot be async, but some lines inside are async (which I need to somehow make sync)

@klaucode Why do you say that the function cannot by async?

@AKX or somehow _orig.apply(...) must be returned after async functions was successfully finished.

@Bergi They're apparently trying to hook into sync methods in another object and interpose async things there – which, afaik, is not going to happen.

Yeah, that's not going to happen.

@Bergi in Node14 (MeteorJS2) was those hooks synchronous, now they are async in Node22 (Meteor3) and I need to somehow solve this problem in this function.

@Bergi Yeah, Ido you have some idea, how to solve it in this function?

@klaucode Why does the method even have to wait for the hooks?

@Bergi because as you can see, the method returns original hook (which is not async), only those problematic methods adding {groupId: "any_group_id"} parameter. And the fook is commimg from MeteorJS Mongo method, which I of course cannot modify.

@Bergi for example TasksCollection.find({_id: "haha"}) => the find method is 'captured' by this function, then added groupId parameter and then call original method.

It was not clear that the hooks are going to modify the arguments, thanks for the clarification.

@Bergi I'm refactoring this, to make it compatible with meteor3 https://github.com/wildhart/meteor-partitioner/blob/3cd93571fc72d5aec659d600a5599f7e4475c69f/hooks.js#L70

@klaucode Afaics, you are hooking on mongo methods. Those are not synchronous anyway, so why not just make them wait for the async meteor stuff?

@Bergi yes, you have truth, but 'find' method is synchronous and this method is making me headache :-(

@klaucode What does find return? Doesn't it run an asynchronous query?

@Bergi thanks a lot Bergi for your patience, I'm very appreciate it! find method returns Cursor object, instead of findOneAsync, insertAsync, updateAsync, removeAsync...etc. which returns Promise.

Ah I guess then you'll need to wrap the methods that operate on the returned cursor as well, as ultimately they'll be used for asynchronously fetching something.

@Bergi those 'commented' asynchronous methods are setting groupId also for the 'find' method. Define groupId after find (in for example fetchAsync) is late I think. Almost all the problems are comming from getting user's groupId by userId, where user is reading from the mongo (await Users.findOneAsync({_id: userId})...) This is the reason, why hooks needs to be async. Is it somehow possible to convert async methods to sync in nodeJS 22?

@klaucode Again, no, this is not possible. Add the group id to the cursor in fetchAsync. Why would you already need it in find if the cursor doesn't immediately use it?

@Bergi it was important to me to get confirmed, that async => sync is impossible without Fibers in Node22. There is fetchAsync and observer, where I must modify cursor, I'm trying it, those methods does not accept query arguments, I need to modify somehow directly in cursor object.

@Bergi I cannot believe, but it seems to be, that it works!!!

@Bergi in the night, I finished package update and...    ....it seems to be, taht it works!!!! Thanks a lot for zour help Bergi
